# first time mvn archetype:generate failed

Tags: maven, maven-3

im just getting started on maven, and im currently following the article from http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project-sect-create-simple.html :

> To start a new Maven project, use the Maven Archetype plugin from the command line. Run the archetype:generate  goal, select archetype #77, and then enter "Y" to confirm and generate the new project:

my environment is :

```
albert@albertkam:~/java/mvn-test> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.1 (r1038046; 2010-11-23 17:58:32+0700)
Java version: 1.6.0_22
Java home: /home/albert/java/jdk1.6.0_22/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.34-12-desktop" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

And here is what i did **mvn archetype:generate** (it seems like the quick start archetype is 98 in my case ?)

```
....
98: remote -> maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
....
360: remote -> wikbook.archetype (-)
361: remote -> circumflex-archetype (-)
362: remote -> javg-minimal-archetype (-)
Choose a number: 98: 98
Choose version: 
1: 1.0-alpha-1
2: 1.0-alpha-2
3: 1.0-alpha-3
4: 1.0-alpha-4
5: 1.0
6: 1.1
Choose a number: 6: 1
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 10f8e92bdec884d353c6b6232feaf3f47e220ec7 but is 4801a224d23f43da2013e35696e278f59c24c1a3 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 10f8e92bdec884d353c6b6232feaf3f47e220ec7 but is 4801a224d23f43da2013e35696e278f59c24c1a3 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.jar (3 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0-alpha-1/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0-alpha-1.pom (299 B at 0.4 KB/sec)
Define value for property 'groupId': : org.albertkam
Define value for property 'artifactId': : firstTest  
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
Define value for property 'package':  org.albertkam: : 
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: org.albertkam
artifactId: firstTest
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: org.albertkam
 Y: : Y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0-alpha-1
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.albertkam
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: org.albertkam
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.albertkam
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: firstTest
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /home/albert/java/mvn-test
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] Error reading POM
org.apache.maven.archetype.old.ArchetypeTemplateProcessingException: Error reading POM
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.old.DefaultOldArchetype.processTemplates(DefaultOldArchetype.java:511)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.old.DefaultOldArchetype.createArchetype(DefaultOldArchetype.java:336)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.processOldArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:149)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.generateProjectFromArchetype(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:71)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:451)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Expected root element 'project' but found 'model' (position: START_TAG seen <model>... @1:7) 
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:4090)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:4025)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:4039)
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.old.DefaultOldArchetype.processTemplates(DefaultOldArchetype.java:503)
        ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:08.416s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 11 16:47:09 WIT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error reading POM -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What is the cause of this error ? Am i missing something ?

And sorry for asking this here, but is there anyway i could wrap the 'code sample' section ? I choosed 'code sample' section for the output messages to preserve the new lines, 'blockquote' doesnt do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the latest version of the archetype 1.1, the default option offered to you (6).

> Choose a number: 6: 6

If you just press enter without entering an option, when a default is presented then the default will be selected and it won't be overridden.